# Error - search members belonging to a group

Tags: groups, search-results

No matches found for:
Group(s) In Client Mailchimp Newsletter ...AND...
Group Status "Added"

I have created a group and was trying to look at the full list of group members but getting above error message. Not sure what is this "status". I was not searching on this

Answer (score 1):

Group Status "Added" is included in the search automatically and is what you probably mean by being 'a member of the group'.  Group Status can have other values such as "Removed" - meaning that the contact was in the group but is no longer.

The message simply means that there are no contacts currently in the Client Mailchimp Newsletter.  Have you tried to add any contacts to that group yet?

Comment: yes I added few hundred records in it yesterday

Comment: If you look at a few of the contacts you added, does the group show up under their Groups tab?  How did you add them to the group (eg individually, using Add to Group from search results, importing, API etc)?